# jQuery: How to stop propagation of Ctrl + A?

Tags: jquery, events, selection, propagation, ctrl

I'm currently developping an application that relies on a map (OpenStreetMap data via Leaflet.js) and markers displayed on the map.

I implemented *selection* for the user, so he can click on markers to select them and Ctrl-click to add markers to selection. This works well.

Now I'd like for the user to be able to select all markers currently on the map by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. The code I use to achieve this looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
      e.stopPropagation();
      // SELECT ALL MARKERS HERE...
    }
  }
});
```

This works as far as triggering on simultaneous Ctrl and A key presses is concerned, the selection is done as I wish.

**My Problem:**
Even though I added the line to stop propagation of the event, the browser (tested on Chrome and Opera) *still* does the usual Ctrl+A-Selection, i.e. additionally to my markers getting selected by my custom selection implementation on the map, *the entire web page is selected*. This is annoying: beside the map there is no text on this page that can be selected, so there is really no point - I would like to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> while my map is shown.

*P.S.
I tried to use the code shown in [How can I disable Ctrl+A (select all) using jquery in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403748/how-can-i-disable-ctrla-select-all-using-jquery-in-a-browser) but was not able to get it to work. Is this functionality really in the API?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose your mistake is that your are using `e.stopPropagation()` which just stops further bubling of an event (as your event is attached to a document - it is useless). Try `e.preventDefault()` instead:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
      e.preventDefault();
      // SELECT ALL MARKERS HERE...
    }
  }
});
```

This works fine for me on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qjzz/)

Comment: Ah, we found it the very same second... :) Here you go good sir, have an accept.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I found the trick:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Stops the browser from performing any default actions. In the case described above this prevents the select-all event normally triggered on <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>.