# Disable select all (ctrl+a)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable any image selecting in my website. I already use this code:

```
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

but still have a problem with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Is there any jQuery or Javascript code to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select all function?

EDIT : this is my website > http://narenjco.ir/ press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in first page , i want to make sparks unselectable

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that. People will still be able to grab content from your website.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It won't prevent users from copying your content, only frustrate them because they encounter unexpected behavior. Nobody disabled right-click menu's nowadays anymore too...

Comment: Java `=/=` JavaScript

Comment: Laughing at 3 the first 3 identical comments 10 seconds from each other.

Comment: Watermark the image instead?

Comment: I don't want to forbidding downloads or protect my content from others , just want to make it unselectable :)

Comment: Blocking ctrl+a isn't enough given that some browsers have a "Select All" option on their Edit menu...

Comment: @Moriuzx That still doesn't say *why* you want to make it unselectable, there aren't many good reasons to do that.

Comment: @Moriuzx if you really want to do this see http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm

Comment: @hob thx but ctrl+a select all things in your link

Comment: You people have all downvoted this question because of assumptions. The use of disabling Ctrl+A in this situation is perfectly plausible.

Comment: if its really that important, you could keep the focus in an invisible textfield. +1 for being concerned about the finer details. don't get discouraged.

Comment: I don't see the point of downvote anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){   
    $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {        
        if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
            if (objEvent.keyCode == 65) {                         

                return false;
            }            
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: You've copied the answer from a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403748/how-can-i-disable-ctrla-select-all-using-jquery-in-a-browser?lq=1

Comment: May be, but it will work

Comment: It's either you copied the answer from Marcx or you both copied the code from a website which I doubt Marcx would do.

Comment: It's ok to copy code from another answer, but if you do so you should credit the original author.

Comment: Use `event.key` instead. `event.keyCode` is `deprecated`.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** I now see that you've applied it to the images within the `.unselectable` class. In Chrome these images *are* unselectable, so the issue appears to be browser-specific. To overcome this problem in whichever browser you're using you'll need to use JavaScript.

---

It's all to do with the usage of your `user-select:none`. Currently, I can't see on your site where this has been applied, however applying it to the `body` tag does prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> from selecting any content (in Chrome at least).

```
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to key press events and return false on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    return e.keyCode != 65 || e.ctrlKey == false; // Return false only on Ctrl+A
}
```

Comment: thx dtech i test it but not working