# How to disable datatable selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, highlight

1. Looking to disable this select functionality within datatables only.
2. Can do the `ctrl+a` as an example is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403748/how-can-i-disable-ctrla-select-all-using-jquery-in-a-browser?lq=1)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Highlight of Text Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `user-select` for the `td` and `th` tags

```
 td, th {
   user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in css to disable selection all over the body

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
```

}

Comment: This stops the entire body of the page, I only need the table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text-table.    Check this if it resolves your problem

Comment: @Aakif If you find a question whose answers also answer the current question, please flag the current question as a duplicate of the question you found.